# Trouble with STLLoader

Tags: three.js

When I try to load my .stl model created by SolidWorks its loaded very giantic. What have I done wrong? I used the example stlloader code and just change *loader.load* .

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/398106/mod1.STL - my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale the mesh after it is created.

```
mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.2 );
```